# how image path is resolved in ezpublish legacy?

Tags: ezpublish

I am working on some existing ezpublish code base. I have two extension `extA` and `extB`. In templates of `extA` i have this code in tpl.

```
<img src={"icons/test.png"|ezimage} height="75" width="75" />
```

Full path of this image becomes
`mysite.com/extension/extA/design/extA/images/icons/test.png`

Now i put the same image code inside a tpl of `extB`. But now the image path resolves to

`mysite.com/design/extB/images/icons/test.png`

Why this path difference? Is there any settings inside ezpublish to control this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following links helped me to find the problem.
https://doc.ez.no/eZ-Publish/Technical-manual/3.10/Reference/Template-operators/URLs/ezimage

https://doc.ez.no/eZ-Publish/Technical-manual/3.9/Reference/Configuration-files/design.ini/ExtensionSettings/DesignExtensions

> If the operator is unable to find the specified file within the "images" subdirectory of the current design, it will attempt to locate it in the "images" subdirectory of the fallback designs or the standard design.

And

> eZ Publish will look for designs in the directory "/extension/ extension_name/design/"

So it first tried to find in path  `mysite.com/extension/extB/design/extB/images/icons/test.png`

and when the image is not there it tries to find from fallback `mysite.com/design/extB/images/icons/test.png`

My image was in first path but it still tried to find from fallback as cache was not updated. After clearing the cache image was found in the first path.

Answer (score 2):

in the design.ini of your extension, you should let the ezpublish know which folder is the folder for design templates. it looks something like this:

```
[ExtensionSettings]
DesignExtensions[]=extB
```

and in the filesystem the path looks like this:

```
{ezpublish_root}/extension/extB/design/extB/....
```

in your example I think the "DesignExtensions[]" is empty and it takes the design folder of ezpublish itself on the root which is the fallback almost for everything in ezpublish.

just to make your example more clear:

"ezimage" will look into "images" folder of your design folder and if the image with that name exists, it will return the path to it.

Comment: thanks for you reply. It helped me to find the right answer. It was actually cache issue. First it tried to find from `design` folder inside extension. It that fails it returns to fallback or standard directory.

Comment: you're welcome but I didn't see any difference between yours and mine. just different wording and of course the cache you had forgotten to clear :)

Comment: Your words are almost same but not same. The difference is you talked about absence of `design.ini` file. If that file is absent default path is same as extension name. Fallback is searched when the image file is not in the design folder of the extension, not when the `design.ini` is absent or the `DesignExtensions` is absent.